# How can I save the resulting images into different folders in python?

Tags: python

I'm reading images from a folder and then applying gamma adjustment on it. Each adjustment produces a modified image with increased/decreased lighting based on the gamma value.

In the given code gamma ranges from 0.1 to 3.0 at intervals of 0.5.So it will output an image for gamma=0.1, then 0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5, and 3.0. I would like to save these images in the same name to different folders based on the gamma value.

Example, if I have an image Eye_01.JPG, then it's modified images with adjusted gamma values have to be saved in different folders for different gamma values (0.1,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5 and 3.0 --> 7 subfolders containing Eye_01.JPG with modified gamma value).

The below script shows the output but I'm not sure how can I save these output images to respective folders.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('--input', help='the input directory', required=True)
ap.add_argument('--dest', help='the destination', required=True)

for path, dirnames, files in os.walk(app.input):
      for filename in files:
           fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
           original = cv2.imread(str(fullname))
           for gamma in np.arange(0.0, 3.5, 0.5):
                        if gamma == 1:
                                continue
                        gamma = gamma if gamma > 0 else 0.1
                        adjusted = adjust_gamma(original, gamma=gamma)
                        cv2.putText(adjusted, "g={}".format(gamma), (10, 30),
                                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 3)
                        cv2.imshow("Images", np.hstack([original, adjusted]))
                        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Please help me!

Comment: `os.makesdir(dirname, exists_ok=True)`, `cv2.imwrite('dirname/filename')`. Filename is a string so you can create new name using string functions - ie. `split()`, slicing `[star:end]`, `replace()`, etc.

Comment: function `os.path.join()` gives string so you don't have to use `str()`